# Globally differentiable non-Lipschitz function that is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a uniformly continuous function $f$ from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is differentiable everywhere, but $f$ is not globally Lipschitz?

The only non-Lipschitz uniformly continuous functions I can come up with are not differentiable everywhere (like $\sqrt{\vert x \vert}$)

Comment: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &, x = 0 \\ x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x^3} &, x \neq 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: I don't think your $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @bartgol Why? It's continuous on $\mathbb R$ and $\to 0$ at $\pm \infty.$

Comment: Oh, right, I did not see right away it goes to 0 at $\infty$. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Every continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $f \to 0$ at $\pm \infty$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$ This still allows for $f'$ to be unbounded, and if that holds, then $f$ is not globally Lipschitz.

Comment: Correct. Graphically, one could take something "nice" like $1/(1+x^2)$ and make *smooth* spikes of amplitude $1/n$  and width $1/n^2$ at every natural number (or any countable set of points). Incidentally, this is also an example of how a $C^\infty$ function approaching 0 at infinity need not have a derivative that approaches zero.

Comment: $\sin(e^x)/(1+x^2)$ also comes to mind.